# Subtitle SubRip (*.srt) Positioning

Tags: video, playback, subtitles

I like SubRib (*.srt) subtitle positioning, as shown below:

```
28
00:02:25,016 --> 00:02:27,393
{\pos(200,250)}- <i>Naw</i>, you're fired.
- What?
```

But that makes me wonder is whether this position will remain the same for the movie file in a different screen resolution?

For example, the dimensions movies is 1920x800 in the 1440x900 monitor, and then played in a 1024x600 monitor.

This method is relative to the dimensions of the movie file or to monitor? Are all the players recognize the positioning in this way? Is there another way to do the positioning?

Comment: it's gotta be relative to the movie, right? But then...which version of the movie, or maybe it has to list the movie size at the beginning of the .srt file?

Comment: For example, 1080p version with dimension 1920x800 and 720p with dimension 1280x720 from same movie. Both played in the 1440x900 monitor and 1024x600 monitor.

Answer (score 1):

A player doesn't have to acknowledge the position of subtitles. So a user could re-position them if he wanted to.
Thats actually the standard way of doing it. What you have there is a custom tag. The .srt format doesn't include any position data for the subtitles. Some players can recognize this sort of custom data and use it but you can't expect that a player will understand it.